# how to add my certifications to linkedin

Tags: training-certification

Since the learning portal has changed, I cannot see an option to add my certifications to LinkedIn anymore. Previously, the portal used to display the certifications with a link to add them to LinkedIn.
Could you please provide me with suggestions and/or point me in the right direction?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this feature is not available on the new learning portal yet. All links to my previous certifications stopped working and I am not able to get a public link to the new certifications too.

So I keep adding my certifications manually to LinkedIn for the time being:

- Go to the section `Licenses and Certifications` on the LinkedIn profile page
- Click the plus icon and fill in the form:

  - `Name` and `Issue date` - this information can be copied from the certificate
  - `Issuing organization` - start typing and select Sitecore from the dropdown
  - `Credential URL` - you can keep this field empty and edit it in future if the Learning portal introduces public certification links again

If you are not sure how to find your certificate on the learning portal, go to the [Learning Home](https://learning.sitecore.com/) and click 'My Transcript' link at the bottom right corner of the page. Then switch to the 'Courses' tab and scan through the list until you find the correct exam. The last column should show a clickable certification icon that allows to download a copy of certificate:
[image: Certification download link]